# Bootstrap grid system conditionally flex col width

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

I have this HTML with bootstrap (3.7) CSS loaded:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6">Stretch ME!</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6">Conditional</div>
</div>
```

The *"Conditional"* div is sometimes there, sometimes not there. How can I make the *"Stretch ME!"* div stretch to `row` width if it is not there, without conditionally rewriting the classes, and preferably with `bootstrap`. Example, something like `class="col-xs-6 but-flex-me-if-over-blank-space"`.

P.S. Can't believe this has not been asked before and bumped up against a lot ... but I can't find a clear answer on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.row {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}
.row .col-xs-6:first-child {
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

flex-grow will fill the available space.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/d8fb36w5/2/

Comment: Ah yes! Thx buddy :).

Comment: @S.Pinkus Welcome. Glad I helped you.